# Assigning Dynamic controller to directive inside compile method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a situation where i want to dynamically assign controller to a directive , but i cannot pass it as argument.

Here is my code

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('home', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'wow';
  $timeout(function() {
    console.log('changed');
    $scope.name = 'wowowow';
  }, 2000);
});


app.directive('modalBox', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    compile: function() {
      return {
        pre: function($scope, $elem, $attr) {
          $elem.attr('ng-controller', 'home');
          $compile($elem.contents())($scope);
        },
        post: function($scope, $elem, $attr, controller) {
          console.log($scope);
        }
      }
    },
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="name"/>{{name}}</div>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div modal-box></div>

</div>
```

I know i can pass the controller as an argument to directive and can simply refer to it as controller property, but i cannot do that because in my real situation the controller name will be decided by a service and i will inject that service to directive in order to grab the controller name.

In short i need to some way to assign controller to directive inside the compile method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the `ng-controller` attribute to `$elem`, which gives the following:

```
<div modal-box="" class="ng-binding" ng-controller="home">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
</div>
```

You are then compiling `$elem.contents()`, which does not contain the `ng-controller` attribute:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
```

Either add the attribute to the input, or compile the entire div.

Note that you need to remove the directive before compiling or there will be an infinite loop:

```
$elem.attr('ng-controller', 'home');
$elem.removeAttr('modal-box');
$compile($elem)($scope);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/A8wNkg6kD3dLByF2eyy2?p=preview

Comment: Thanks , when i was compiling the $elem earlier , it used to hang the browser , i saw you removed modal-box attribute , may i know why ?

Comment: Opps, I edited out too much of my answer. If you don't remove it the compile service will compile your directive againg, which contains a call to compile, which will compile the directive again, and so on.